Change background color of the parent element in CKEditor content
I am using CKEditor and one thing I cannot figure out is how to change the background color of the parent that hold the elements that are inserted from the toolbar.
To be clear, I do not want to change the color of the CKEditor itself (like changing it to dark mode etc)
I'm referring to when I click a toolbar item like "Heading 1". A h1 element is added to the canvas of the CKEditor and I can style that h1 anyway I like. It's the canvas itself I want to style. In this case, change the background color.
I'm using Vue and I have this:
    <script setup>
    import { ref } from "vue";

    import ClassicEditor from "@ckeditor/ckeditor5-build-classic";

    const editor = ref(ClassicEditor);
    const editorData = ref(
      "<div style='background-color:red;width:300px;height:300px;'><p>I want the entire background of the contents inside of the editor to be red (or any other color)</p></div>"
    );
    const editorConfig = ref({});
    </script>

Then in my template, I have this:
    <template>
      <img alt="Vue logo" src="./assets/logo.png" />

      <ckeditor
        :editor="editor"
        v-model="editorData"
        :config="editorConfig"
      ></ckeditor>
    </template>

This isn't doing what I want. Here is a codesandbox that implements the code: https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/vue-3-gyhpz4
I want to do this because I will eventually save the contents and retrieve them later.
How do I change (style) the canvas elements are sitting on an CKEditor?
Thanks

Just to be sure: do you want to style a contenteditable div that holds the contents?

If that is the div that holds the elements added from the toolbar, then yes

It holds all: the elements added from the toolbar and the elements entered manually by a user. There is no separate container for the ones from a toolbar.

Ok, cool. Is there a way to style it?

Yes, it can be styled with CSS - I've just posted an answer.

Set the value of --ck-color-base-background CSS variable in the #app or, more specifically, in the #app .ck-content:
#app .ck-content {
  --ck-color-base-background: red;
}


Yes, this worked.  I can add the dynamic changing myself now that I know what to change. Thanks
